# Possibility of using value types as reference types in C#

Tags: c#, oop

Might seems odd, but is it somehow possible to use value types as reference types in C# ?

I am using a library where there is a method that needs the message type to be passed.

The thing is that it does not accept value types as message type, and all I want to receive as a message is a Guid, now if I do the following

```
public class GUID
    {
        public  Guid Guid { get; set; }
    }
```

And pass  GUID instead of Guid, it is working.

This made me think, is there an alternative way of overriding this issue?
and if there is not any, why is that? Is not there a real life examples when primitive types are actually objects?

Comment: **Why** doesn't the library allow you to use value types?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen as a serialization library author: I totally get it that a `struct` root makes life hard in a range of ways; that doesn't actually amaze me

Comment: Hmm, you can't arbitrarily do this.  My crystal ball says that this is actually a pinvoked method, you forgot to use `ref` in the parameter declaration.

Comment: In general you can assign your value type to object (`object boxed = 1`) and  voila - you are using value type as reference type.

Comment: @Evk, thanks, seems like my answer

Comment: @HansPassant a PInvoke'd method is very unlikely to work with classes but not structs - more like the other way around

Comment: Hmm, no, wrapping it in a class is a simple way to create a pinned pointer to the value at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `object` doesn't work, you could perhaps use:

```
public sealed class Box<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then you at least don't need to define lots of types. Your guid would be `Box<Guid>`, obviously.